# WordPress: Front-end editor to add extra CSS to website

Tags: css, wordpress

I need to create a plugin that allows me to select any button or any part of the website and add extra CSS to it on hover or on click.

I have managed to consume REST API within WordPress, add menus and submit forms, but I have no idea how to accomplish this task yet.

I would appreciate any suggestion.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use Javascript or jQuery to detect the hover/click.

First, you need a way of targeting a specific button. You can do this by assigning each of your buttons a unique ID.

Then you'll need to watch for the mouseenter or click events. In jQuery this can be done with the [mouseenter()](https://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) and [click()](https://api.jquery.com/click/) functions.

You can then grab the unique ID of a button when it is clicked on/hovered over like so

```
$('button').mouseenter(function(e){
    // here you would add CSS for e.target.id
})
```

From there, you can form specific CSS rules that target the specific button that was hovered over/clicked on.

To save your CSS, you would need to send an Ajax call back to WordPress with the CSS rules you would like to create.

And then in your plugin's PHP code, you would need to create an Ajax endpoint that is able to store your CSS rules in the database. I would probably put it in your page's post metadata.

And finally you would need to add a function that injects the CSS stored in the database onto the page.

Good luck.

Comment: thanks that was really helpful i'll try it